# How to deal with tags corresponding to the question / problem, and not with the actual answer / solution?

Tags: discussion, tags

Here is a short and generic example introducing my issue :

### **Fictitious example**

**Question : What should I do to achieve X ?**

I'm currently trying to do **X** (details, output, ...), so I tried to use languages / libraries **Y** and **Z** this way :

`Some code in both languages / with both libraries ...`

But I still can't get the desired result. What am I doing wrong ?

**Tags** : **Y** and **Z**

**Answer :** (And let's assume that it is a 100% correct answer !)

You simply can't do that with **Y** and **Z**, but instead you should use **W** that way : ...

---

Now my question is :

I want to edit the post and change tags in order to get a better categorization of the post. I'm not necessarily OP or the one who gave the correct answer, but just a random editor.

**What should I do with tags on the question ?**

- Remove **Y** and **Z** tags, and add **W** tag
- Add **W** tag only
- Nothing at all

At the moment, I think that adding **W** tag, and keeping **Y** and **Z** tags is the best thing to do since it could help next users with a similar question to get to this question (and then to the solution), but I'm very unsure.

Comment: Those are good tags. If the problem uses library **Y**, then tagging with **Y** means the question will be seen by people who also are interested in library **Y**. So, more qualified eyeballs. And if the OP doesn't know about solution **W**, how could they ever tag their question with **W**?

Comment: @MrLister Now that you're asking, I just realized that it might be unclear that I'm talking as an editor, not as being OP. I will rephrase the question to makes it more clear.

Comment: You mean you want to change the tags after the answer has been given? Because somehow the nature of the answer changes the aspects of the question? I don't think that's a good course of action, really.

Comment: Categorizing a question/answer pair by its actual content rather than what the OP originally thought is was is an important and good thing to do, @MrLister; 99% of the value of an SO question is in the future, when other people are searching for it.

Comment: @JoshCaswell You do have a point. However, I couldn't recommend removing existing tags, ever. So only add new tags if 1) there's room for them and 2) if they _really_ contribute to the question.

Comment: You're right that it's important to pick the right ones, @MrLister, but there's five tag slots, and personally I've very rarely needed more in all the edits I've done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You certainly shouldn't remove tags **Y** and **Z**. These are what the OP used and presumably what other people will use when asking questions on the same topic.

As to whether you should add tag **W** - that's a little more problematical. In your example it might be sensible as you've stated that using **W** is the 100% correct answer. However, that's not always the case. It also might be the case that changes to **Y** and **Z** mean that you can do what you want to do without using **W** and adding that tag would confuse things.

Therefore on balance I would say that the following:

> - Nothing at all

is your action of choice.

Comment: I think you should vote to close such questions.

Comment: @mehow - what's your argument for doing that? The answer "you can't do that with `X`" is a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: Re-read the question please. You probably wouldn't even get to an answer with such a question. I have seen many real questions based on the blueprint by the OP and I think 99% of those were either too-broad or primarily opinion based. I mean how often do you have a **specific** programming related question where an answer is: "use another programming language"? or where you can really properly justify the reason to "use one library/language over the other"?

Comment: @mehow When the library X just **can't** do the job, or i.e when people try to do some client work with server side languages. It's such examples that I see quite often that led me to asking this. However I partly agree with you,  it's not too broad or opinion based, but mostly duplicates or low researches that, yes, should be closed.